# AWS Elastic BeanStalk Phantom Bug

Tags: amazon-web-services, phantomjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, html-pdf

I'm experiencing a bug when being on production in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, otherwise it works well, both locally and in Heroku. Logs say:

```
html-pdf: Failed to load PhantomJS module. You have to set the path to the PhantomJS binary using 'options.phantomPath'
```

Indeed I'm using `html-pdf` but for some reason it fails on AWS EB. EB is: 64bit Amazon Linux/4.14.1 and Node 10.17

Answer (score 0):

I JUST managed to figure a solution out to a similar problem in my environment. Running node 10.15. Perhaps you've already resolved this-- if so, congrats! And full disclaimer, I'm not an expert with Elasticbeanstalk configuration, but wanted to share a potential solution.

Try adding a yaml configuration file in `/.ebextension` with the below contents:

```
commands:
    99-installphantom:
        env:
            PATH: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64/bin/
        command: npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt --unsafe-perm
```

This forces the install of phantomjs globally, and the `--unsafe-perm` flag runs the script with root privileges.

Got the hint by using the last comment in [this issue](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/583), which then caused a 'permission denied error'-- hence unsafe-perm.

For reference, I also have the below Elasticbeanstalk settings, which apparently just aren't quite enough to npm install everything...:

`/.ebextensions/00_change_npm_permissions.config`

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_set_tmp_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm
```

`.npmrc` in the same directory as `package.json`

```
# Force npm to run node-gyp also as root, preventing permission denied errors in AWS with npm
unsafe-perm=true
```